# copy one database data to another database in real time transaction in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have two sql servers 1 an d 2 and i want copy all data from "A" database which is on server 1 to database "B" which is on server 2.
whenever data update insert or delete from database "A" it should be reflected on database "B".

I trying to user replication process but getting some error 
"Sql server replication requires the actual server name to make connection to the server"

Plz give solution step by step

Comment: The error message seems rather self-explanatory? Have you done what it says?

Comment: SQL Server's [replication documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx) is very good and includes [tutorials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337389.aspx).